# Obtener datos JSON del LocalStorage y meterlos en un array

Tags: javascript, local-storage, javascript-objeto

Estaba realizando un programa en JavaScript para poder mostrar los datos que esten en el LocalStorage pero lo primero que quiero hacer es atrapar todos los datos que en este caso seria Objetos [json](/questions/tagged/json) y meterlos en un arreglo, esto es lo que tengo pero me arroja un `undefined` y si tengo datos ya en el `LocalStorage`.

```
function mostrarDatos(){
  console.log("Mostrando datos!");
  let cajaDatosPeople = document.querySelector("#list-people");
  let personaToString = document.createElement("li");
  datos = localStorage;
  console.log(datos[0]);
}
```

Si muestro solamente datos me arroja esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Dónde ocurre el `undefined`? En tu código no veo ningún manejo de datos de ningún tipo.

Comment: Ya se me olvido añadir lo ultimo que pena, ocurre cuando quiero seleccionar el datos[0] el primer objeto JSON de el localStorage

Comment: Eso no hace nada. Debería ser `datos=window.localStorage;` ¿no?

Comment: De las dos maneras me sirve, lo que no me sirve es el console.log(datos[0]); para acceder a un elemento de esa lista de datos

Comment: Pon un `console.log(datos);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Listo ahí tendría dos objetos

Comment: No tienes un array para hacer algo como `datos[0]`, donde estarías queriendo obtener el índice `0` de ese array.

Comment: Si quieres guardar los objetos dentro de un array tendrás que hacer [algo parecido a lo explicado aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357615/5587982).

Comment: Dale muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript te proporciona el objeto [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), mediante el cual puedes realizar el acceso a los datos almacenados ahí de la siguiente forma.

**setItem:**

```js
localStorage.setItem(key, datos);
```

Te permite guardar información en tipo string , de tal manera que si necesitas almacenar objetos, arrays, es común usar `JSON.stringify()`, para parsear a un string y almacenarlo.

```js
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(objeto));
```

**getItem**

```js
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

Te permite acceder al contenido almacenado de el registrp que le proporciones como key, de igual forma como la escritura te regresara un objeto String, y si tu información es un objeto de igual forma es comun usar `JSON.parse()`.

```js
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
```

Para tu caso especifico seria de la siguiente forma.

```js
var dato1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jscarrillo01'));
var dato1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jscarrillo02'));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!